# замена элемента строки без использования replace

Tags: python

Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. не идет замена. Спасибо за помощь*

```
def my_string_replace(args):
    a = input('букву: ')
    b = input('замену: ')
    args = list(args)
    args = ' '.join(args)

    for i in args:
        if a == i:
            a = b

    return args

print(my_string_replace('Hello world'))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сроки в питоне не изменяются. Необходимо будет создать новую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```py
def my_string_replace(args):
    a = input('букву: ')
    b = input('замену: ')
    ret = [b if i == a else i for i in args]
    return ''.join(ret)

print(my_string_replace('Hello world'))
```

Или так, если уж хотите через списки:

```
def my_string_replace(args):
    a = input('букву: ')
    b = input('замену: ')
    args = list(args)
    for i,x in enumerate(args):
        if x == a:
            args[i] = b
    return ''.join(args)

print(my_string_replace('Hello world'))
```

А у вас что-то не очень осмысленное в коде происходит. Например, тут вы просто вставили между буквами пробелы. Зачем??

```
    args = list(args)
    args = ' '.join(args)
```

А тут вы поменяли `a` на `b`, но `args` при этом ведь никак не меняется. И строку нельзя менять всё-равно, а у вас `args` уже опять строка тут, а не список.

```
    for i in args:
        if a == i:
            a = b
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я ночью совсем тупила))

Comment: точно, это я же не args меняла, а пыталась что-то бессмысленное сделать. все напутала.спасибо

Comment: не туда понаписывала, как говорится, когда понятие какое-то имеешь, а голова не варит, лучше спать